# Browser based InfoPath form is randomly open as InfoPath filler form

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I have created InfoPath 2010 browser based form ( Administrator Approval Form with SharePoint 2010 ) . All the functionalities working correctly.

But when  going to create a from or trying to open a form ; randomly it is opening as a InfoPath filler form.

Do I need to do any change to  work this browser make the form browser based properly…?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the Document Library settings?

Please follow this steps:

1. Go to the library when the forms are created.
2. Go to the Library Settings.
3. From there go to Advance Library Settings.
4. On the Document Library Advanced Settings page, in the Opening Documents in the Browser section, under Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents, check the "Open in the Browser" option.

I hope this helps